# Validating Kana Input

Tags: validation, language-agnostic, unicode, cjk

I am working on an application that allows users to input Japanese language characters. I am trying to come up with a way to determine whether the user's input is a Japanese kana (hiragana, katakana, or kanji).

There are certain fields in the application where entering Latin text would be inappropriate and I need a way to limit certain fields to kanji-only, or katakana-only, etc.

The project uses UTF-8 encoding. I don't expect to accept JIS or Shift-JIS input.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you basically need to just check whether each Unicode character is within a particular range. The [Unicode code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) should be a good starting point.

If you're using .NET, my [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) library has some Unicode range support - it's primitive, but it should do the job. I don't have the source to hand right now, but will update this post with an example later if it would be helpful.

Comment: Jon, you wouldn't happen to have the source handy, would you?

Comment: @Zack: Follow the link and you can download it :)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure of a perfect answer, but there is a Unicode range for [katakana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana) and [hiragana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana) listed on Wikipedia. (Which I would expect are also available from [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/) as well.)

- Hiragana: Unicode: 3040-309F
- Katakana: Unicode: 30A0–30FF

Checking those ranges against the input should work as a validation for hiragana or katakana for Unicode in a language-agnostic manner.

For kanji, I would expect it to be a little more complicated, as I 
expect that the Chinese characters used in Chinese and Japanese are both included in the same range, but then again, I may be wrong here. (I can't expect that Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese to be included in the same range...)

Answer (score 2):

oh oh! I had this one once... I had a regex with the hiragana, then katakana and then the kanji.  I forget the exact codes, I'll go have a look.

regex is great because you double the problems.  And I did it in PHP, my choice for extra strong auto problem generation

--edit--

```
$pattern = '/[^\wぁ-ゔァ-ヺー\x{4E00}-\x{9FAF}_\-]+/u';
```

I found this [here](http://forums.devshed.com/regex-programming-147/japanese-regex-php-getting-kanji-characters-586534.html), but it's not great... I'll keep looking

--edit--
I looked through my portable hard drive.... I thought I had kept that particular snippet from the last company... sorry.

Comment: I used to use the same range for kanjis(4E00~9FAF), but checked it in the unicode charts and found that the full range is a bit larger: 4E00~9FFF. Though, it probably contains characters not used (anymore?) in the Japanese language.

Comment: Writing Japanese characters in the source file is a bad practice.